# Send duplicate messages from the database to the Telegram channel

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, telegram-bot

I wrote this program with Python, which takes a few jokes from the database and publishes them on the Telegram channel:

```
import requests
import sqlite3
import random
import re

def send(msg,token,ca):
    url = f"https://api.telegram.org/bot{token}/sendMessage?chat_id={ca}&text={msg}"
    mypay = {"UrlBox":url,"AgentBox" : "Google Chrome","VersionsList" : "HTTP/1.1","MethodList" : "GET"}
    http = requests.post("http://httpdebugger.com/tools/ViewHttpHeaders.aspx",data=mypay)

conn = sqlite3.connect("jokjok.db")
c = conn.cursor()
emoji_list = ["","","",""]
emoji_taki = ["","","","","",""]
chand = 5


c.execute(f"SELECT * FROM jok ORDER BY ROWID ASC LIMIT {chand}")
for i in list(range(chand)):
    jok = str(c.fetchone())
    tmp = jok
    jok = jok.replace("(","")
    jok = jok.replace(")","")
    jok = jok.replace("'","")
    jok = jok.replace("\\u200c"," ")
    jok = jok.replace("\"","")
    jok = jok.replace("[","")
    jok = jok.replace("]","")
    jok = jok.replace("\\n","""
    """)
    jok = jok.replace("\\","")
    jok = re.sub(",$", "", jok)
    jok = f"{jok} {random.choice(emoji_list)}"

    send(jok,"mykey","@jok_khone_channel")
    if random.choice([False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,True,True,True,True]):
        send(random.choice(emoji_taki),"mykey","@jok_khone_channel")
```

My problem is that if I run this program once, several jokes will be sent, but if I run the program again, the same jokes will be sent and the jokes will be repeated.
I want to make sure new jokes are sent every time.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new table `sent_jokes` with the columns `(joke_id, is_send)`, where you keep track of the jokes that you've already sent. And then change you SQL query to

```
SELECT * FROM jok  
JOIN sent_jokes ON jok.id=sent_jokes.joke_id 
WHERE is_send is FALSE 
ORDER BY ROWID ASC LIMIT {chand}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm not going to do all the work for you :) 

You need to create a new database, the same way you have created the `jokjok.db`. You can call this database `sent_jokes`, and create it with two columns, one called `joke_id` and the other one `is_send`. Every time that you send a joke you can update the table `sent_jokes` with the id of the joke you send and mark it with `is_send = True`. Then, before sending a new joke you need to check in the database if the joke has been sent already.